# How to use FuelSDK-PHP in the Non-prod and the Prod contexts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I'm using https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP and I can update a data extension based in another. I would like to do the same but I have 2 different contexts. The non-prod and the prod one. I use a different clientid and secretid depending on which context I want to use.

Is it possible to connect both same time and retrieve data from the Non-Prod to update the Prod one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FROM Salesforce Technical Support

Regarding your question, to clarify, it sounds like you want to be able to access a data extension from different business units. Two types of data extensions exist:

(1) Shared data extensions: These are accessed from the top-level MID when using the API. Your app in AppCenter (if using client ID/secret) must be associated with the top-level MID.

(2) Data extensions: Unless they are in the "Shared" folder in an enterprise, data extensions are not shared between business units. As such your AppCenter app must have access to the business unit in question.

However, **at no time** can a data extension exist in two separate business units. Even shared data extensions are again only accessible at the enterprise level.